# Angular 2 how to refresh forms after http post

Tags: javascript, angular, http, post, request

I am rather new in Angular and my problem is:
I have main component which have some child components like form component, tab component, status component.

On main component init I do a request for data (let's say i subscribe it to Object1). This date are used in forms, and status component.

But I have a tab component  where i have on it's init another request (let's say Object2). On this component i have a button which runs http post (updating Object2) and on backend side it change one value from Object1 (status value in status component).

How i can reload all main component to see that Object1 is changed after succes on http post in tab component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On main component init I do a request for data (let's say i subscribe
>   it to Object1). This date are used in forms, and status component.

Use `Outputs` to call this method again.

Basically you just need to make your data request again.

E.g Component 2 Post button

```
@Output() refresh = new EventEmitter();
post(){
   //make http.post request
   .subscribe(
     res => console.log(res), 
     err => console.error(err), 
     () => this.refresh.emit();
 )

}
```

Component 1 that needs to refresh - template

```
<component-2 (refresh)="getData()"></component-2>
```

Where getData() = the same method you used to request data the first time.